# How to import code into a contract

Tags: go-ethereum, solc, solidity-0.8.x, docker

I have a contract that needs to be compiled with solc so I can get Go bindings.

```
$ tree
.
├── openzeppelin
├── Swap.sol
└── @uniswap
```

```
pragma solidity >0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

import { IUniswapV2Pair } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Factory } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Router02 } from "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
```

This compiles and deploys on Remix.
But when I compile it locally using:

```
docker run -v /my-path/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.18 --allow-paths=/sources/solc -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Swap.sol
```

I get:

```
Error: Source "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> sources/solc/Swap.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import { IUniswapV2Pair } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> sources/solc/Swap.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import { IUniswapV2Factory } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> sources/solc/Swap.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import { IUniswapV2Router02 } from "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have to fix it by downloading the code and then prefix it with "./":

```
import { IUniswapV2Pair } from "./@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Factory } from "./@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Router02 } from "./@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
```

I don't like it because I might not get the proper version of the imported contract.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: In your local directory where are the `@uniswap/v2-...` libs installed relative to your project root? I suspect they're located in `./@uniswap/v2-...` hence why you have to prepend the import with `./`

Comment: And yes, @uniswap/v2-... libs are installed relative to your project root.
I added tree to the code above.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way around this directly with solc, you could consider using a framework like hardhat or foundry which will allow you to import external dependencies with "@uniswap/..."

Comment: The problem using Hardhat is that I don't get any Go bindings. That forces me to use solc.